Sound suddenly stops working while microphone is still usable
I have a Logitech H390 headset. One day, while using it, my headset suddenly stopped playing anything. The device name was changed to "Hi Res USB-C AUDIO". I can still continue to customize the sound through the headset and use my microphone, but I can no longer hear anything.
I also tried it on 2 other computers, but the problem still occurs. The volume is set to the highest level.
How can I fix this problem???
Here's what changed:



what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

I have stated my problem above, is there any way to fix it??

maybe the headset is defective

Have you looked at the Logitech support site? Have you checked for updated drivers? Removed the wrongly-named hardware and installed fresh drivers? What was happening on your computer around the time this issue began? Have you tried rolling back? The fact the problem occurs on multiple computers would indicate this is more likely to be a problem with the headset, so have you checked to see if a different/similar headset works OK on these computers?
